# Library to convert dates from any format to any format in PHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, date

There is a library for PHP where I can inform a date as a String, the current format used in the String and the output format to some function/method to convert the date?

Example:

```
convertDate('d/m/Y', 'y.m.d', '11/03/1991') # will output 91.03.11
```

I didn't find a simple way to do this only with PHP functions because they expect a date in a specific format (eg.: `MM/DD/YYYY`) and not any format.

I can do this with some coding for specific formats, but I'm searching something broader because I think it will be useful in several projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime objects - read about them in the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php, particularly the createFromFormat() method http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: Thanks, it was this I was searching for, simple and powerful.

Answer (score 0):

By replacing the "/" with "-" strtotime produces the date you want:

```
$myTime = "11/03/1991";
$theDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $myTime)));
echo $theDate; //displays 1991-03-11
```

Supposedly it does this because:

> Hyphens suggest ISO date format, dots suggest European, and slashes
>   are American.

Comment: @Qualcuno - It was a comment regarding how the code detects what it thinks you want to do with it - not how you actually write it.